# Colección llega NULL al iniciar otro activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, firestore

estoy haciendo consultas a firestore y como sabrán es asincrono y es por ello que creé esta interface Callback, para poder obtener la data con ayuda de la misma, lo cual me funciona bien en el `MainActivity` y según he comprobado a través de un mensaje `Log()`, la sublista también están correctamente.

Pero, al pasar a otra activity, ahí es donde sucede el problema y no sé que sucede y a qué se deba.

Les dejo parte de mi código:

**Callback interface**

```
interface Callback {
    void myResponseCallBack(List<Menu> menuList);
}
```

**MenuService**

```
public void getMenus(Callback callBack){
    List<Menu> documents= new ArrayList<>();
    db.collection("Menu")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
            queryDocumentSnapshots.forEach(querySnapshot -> {
                Menu menu = querySnapshot.toObject(Menu.class);
                documents.add(menu);
            });
            callBack.myResponseCallBack(documents);
        });
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);

    menuService.getMenus(menuList -> {
        menus = menuList;
        initRecyclerView(menus);
    });

}

private void initRecyclerView(List<Menu> menus){
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewMenu);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MenuAdapter(menus, this));

    //Log.d(TAG, "LISTA: " + menus.get(0).getComidas());
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(Menu menu) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ComidaActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Menu", menu);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**MenuAdapter**

```
class MenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuAdapter.MenuViewHolder> {

    private List<Menu> menus;
    private MenuClickListener menuClickListener;

    public MenuAdapter(List<Menu> menus) {
        this.menus = menus;
    }

    public MenuAdapter(List<Menu> menus, MenuClickListener menuClickListener) {
        this.menus = menus;
        this.menuClickListener = menuClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MenuAdapter.MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_menu, parent, false);
        return new MenuViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MenuViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.menuName.setText(menus.get(position).getNombreMenu());

        Glide.with(holder.menuImg)
                .load(menus.get(position).getMenuImg())
                .into(holder.menuImg);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view ->
                menuClickListener.onItemClick(menus.get(position))
        );
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return menus.size();
    }

    static class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView menuName;
        ImageView menuImg;

        public MenuViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            menuName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMenuName);
            menuImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivMenuImg);
        }
    }
 }
```

**ComidaActivity**

```
public class ComidaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ComidaAdapter.ComidaClickListener {

    List<Comida> comidas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comida);

        Menu menu = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Menu");
        comidas = menu.getComidas();

        initRecyclerView();
    }

    private void initRecyclerView(){
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewComida);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
        ComidaAdapter comidaAdapter = new ComidaAdapter(comidas);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(comidaAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAddToCartClick(Comida comida) {

    }
}
```

**ComidaAdapter**

```
class ComidaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ComidaAdapter.ComidaViewHolder> {

    private List<Comida> comidas;
    private ComidaClickListener comidaClickListener;

    public ComidaAdapter(List<Comida> comidas) {
        this.comidas = comidas;
    }

    public ComidaAdapter(List<Comida> comidas, ComidaClickListener comidaClickListener) {
        this.comidas = comidas;
        this.comidaClickListener = comidaClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ComidaAdapter.ComidaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_comida, parent, false);
        return new ComidaViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ComidaViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.nombreComida.setText(comidas.get(position).getNombreComida());
        holder.descripcionComida.setText(comidas.get(position).getDescripcionComida());
        holder.precioComida.setText(String.valueOf(comidas.get(position).getPrecioComida()));
        holder.addToCartButton.setOnClickListener(event -> {
            comidaClickListener.onAddToCartClick(comidas.get(position));
        });

        Glide.with(holder.fotoComida)
                .load(comidas.get(position).getFotoComida())
                .into(holder.fotoComida);

        //holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> comidaClickListener.onItemClick(comidas.get(position)));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return comidas.size();
    }

    static class ComidaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView nombreComida;
        private TextView descripcionComida;
        private TextView precioComida;
        private TextView addToCartButton;
        private ImageView fotoComida;

        public ComidaViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nombreComida = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNombreComida);
            //descripcionComida = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescripcionComida);
            precioComida = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrecioComida);
            addToCartButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addToCartButton);
            fotoComida = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivFotoComida);
        }
    }

    public interface ComidaClickListener{
        void onAddToCartClick(Comida comida);
    }
  }
```

Según este mensaje, indica que la sublista está vacía y como dije, comprobé a través de un `Log()` en el `MainActivity` y si está correcto. ¿Cómo soluciono este problema para que aparezca correctamente todo? gracias.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
> at pe.pepito.test.adapter.ComidaAdapter.getItemCount(ComidaAdapter.java:58)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:4044)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3534)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)

Comment: Parece que `menus` es `null` en el adapter. Muestra el código completo del adapter para revisar.

Comment: Uhmm, no creo que sea ello, porque he estado probando con `Log()` , por ejemplo en el `MainActivity`, llega y pinta correctamente los otros campos en pantalla. Ya edité el `MenuAdapter`.

Comment: No veo claro el contexto aún. ¿`MenuAdapter` es una clase aparte? ¿Cargas tu lista `menus` en el constructor de dicha clase? Hay que averiguar por qué es `null` en ese contexto.

Comment: Bueno, veo que ya pusiste el código completo de `MenuAdapter`, eso, a primera vista, parece correcto. El problema al parecer ocurre en `ComidaAdapter`, muestra la clase completa. Ni siquiera se ve el método `getItemCount()` de esa clase, que es donde estaría ocurriendo el error.

Comment: @A.Cedano , ya edité `ComidaAdapter` , la sublista la paso por el constructor, no veo problema en ello jeje.

Comment: Todo parece correcto. ¿Podrías poner un punto de interrupción dentro del método `onBindViewHolder` de `ComidaAdapter` e inspeccionar en ese punto los objetos?

Comment: Y, ¿verificaste que `comidas` no es `null` en `ComidaActivity`?

Comment: Al parecer el problema estaba en ComidaAdapter , no se estaba enviando un campo  (descripciónComida)

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada si vas a enviar un objeto o lista de objetos, tu objeto debe implementar la interface `Parcelable` o `Serializable`:

```
class Menu(): Parcelable {
 ...
 ...
}
```

Este me parece que es el problema principal.